# Is it possible to change the font of a JavaScript from HTML?

Tags: javascript, fonts

Is it possible to change the font in a JavaScript from a snippet of html-code?

I want to "force" the JS to display a local font, but I can't change the JS (it's not my script, and it's chaotic).

The JS is generated by a crossword program that only lets you choose between "times new roman" and "Sans serif" when you export the files to web-pages. Everything is exported in lower-case, which I was able to fix by using "text-transform: uppercase" to make all the letters upper-case. Why is it not possible to do the same with a font? (And yes; it works everywhere else on the page).

Here's the full code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta NAME="Generator" CONTENT="Crossword Compiler (www.crossword-compiler.com)">

//this is my stylesheet to call @font-face.
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" /> 

//this is from the original code. I've only added 'fatalityregular':
<STYLE TYPE="text/css"
{  "font-family: fatalityregular, Arial, Times, sans-serif";
}></STYLE>

//this whole section looks like this when you export the puzzle to web:
<!--
BODY, .Clues, .GridClues { font-size: -3pt; font-family: 'fatalityregular', Arial, Times, sans-serif;}
-->
<!--
.PuzTitle {
font-size: 15pt; color: #800000; font-weight: bold;
 }
.CopyTag {
font-size: 10pt; color: #000000
 }
-->

</HEAD>

<BODY TEXT="#000000" BGCOLOR="#ffffff">
//this is what I use to fix Times/Arial. With MYFONT I won't need this (it's all uppercase):
<span style="text-transform: uppercase"> 

<script src="CrosswordCompilerApp/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="CrosswordCompilerApp/raphael.js"></script>
<script src="CrosswordCompilerApp/crosswordCompiler.js"></script>
<script src="MyCrossword.js"></script> //This is where I want MYFONT to be used.
<script>
$(function(){
$("#CrosswordCompilerPuz").CrosswordCompiler(CrosswordPuzzleData,null,    
{SUBMITMETHOD:"POST",PROGRESS :  "" , ROOTIMAGES: "CrosswordCompilerApp/CrosswordImages/"  } );});
</script>
<div id="CrosswordCompilerPuz"></div>

</span>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: FYI, `<!--  my comment here -->` is a comment in HTML. So anything in it will be ignored by the browser.

Comment: You should try to use css, not javascript, for any stylistic changes to your page. As mentioned by @forgivenson your css rules in the head are commented out. You should switch the comment tags to style tags, like this `<style> BODY, .Clues, .GridClues { font-size: -3pt; font-family: 'Font_I_Want', sans-serif;  } </style>`

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have used fontsquirrel to generate my font. It's in stylesheet.css. It works fine everywhere, except for in the crossword (which is generated by the program I create the crosswords in). Could it be that the problem here is that the JS overwrites everything else? Like I said, when I export the crossword to web-files, I have to choose between Times New Roman or Sans Serif. Should I change something in on of the applet scripts, perhaps? I have no clue how to solve this -.-

Answer (score 0):

```
 <span id="my-span" onclick="return change_font();" style="text-transform: uppercase;">Your Text</span>

 <script>
   function change_font(){
     document.getElementById("my-span").style.fontFamily = "Times New Roman";
   }
 </script>
```

Comment: This also works everywhere, except for where I need it to work:p

Could it be that the problem here is that the JS overwrites everything else? Like I said, when I export the crossword to web-files, I have to choose between Times New Roman or Sans Serif. 

Should I change something in the main script, perhaps? The problem is that I have no idea what to change and where to change it. The app-script itself looks like this: 

FontStyle|FontWeight|LetterUsed|FontSize|float|white|new|ViewHeight|Squares|selected|alphabet|show|, etc.

Do I need a program to edit JS? 

(Sorry if I'm just plain stupid!)

Comment: Try this and let me know..put this code above your html and make it !important to your css in style tag <style> BODY, .Clues, .GridClues, #my-span { font-size: -3pt !important; font-family: 'Font_I_Want', sans-serif !important; } </style>

Comment: Thanks for helping! I couldn't get that to work either, though. I have edited my question, so now the whole code is there. Could you show me exactly which parts to edit (just in case I didn't do it right)?

BTW, I got a not-very-helpful reply from the maker when I asked what to change and where - Maybe this means more to you than to me: "I don't think it usually matters where you put the style, as long as it is sufficiently specific to the element you want to change. The font may currently being overridden by the applet font, in which case you may need a more specific css tag."

Comment: your written code in style tag is wrong..your css code will not work till you will not provide any class or id name selector...so add id in your <span> tag and change code in <style> tag like this...<span id="my_span"> and in style...<style type="text/css">#my_span{ font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important; text-transform: uppercase !important;}</style>

Comment: Still working fine everywhere, but not in the crossword. I think I'll just give up. The only JS where I can find a mention of a font is in "Raphael.js", where it says "font:'10px "Arial"',"font-family":'"Arial"',"font-size":"10"" somewhere in all the chaos.